# how to remove multiple emacs instances in windows taskbar

Tags: windows, emacs, taskbar

If I launch emacs with runemacs.exe, the window in the taskbar is associated with an emacs.exe process rather than a runemacs.exe process.  This means that if I pin runemacs.exe, I get two emacs icons in the taskbar.  If I pin emacs.exe, I get a console.  How do I have my cake and eat it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like an option:

- http://sachachua.com/blog/2012/06/making-gnu-emacs-play-well-on-microsoft-windows-7/

> To pin Emacs to your task bar, right-click on the Emacs icon in the task bar. Right-click on the small Emacs icon that appears, and click on Properties. Change the target to `c:\emacs\bin\runemacs.exe`, and change the start directory to whichever directory you prefer.

A related answer:

- https://superuser.com/questions/259146/why-latest-emacs-version-dont-support-windows-7-taskbar

Comment: lol, that was hilariously simple.  I assumed the target was inextricably associated with the app it identifies with.  Guess not!

Comment: Right?? I bookmarked these myself, I feel like I've run into other apps that behave similarly in Win7+ (looking at you, `cygwin`).

Comment: Worked for me, just now, on windows 10 anniversary edition.

Answer (score 1):

I have wrestled with the same problem. What I did:

```
- I made a shortcut which has runemacs.exe as the target.
- set environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR c:\path-to-emacs\runemacs.exe
- associate the files with certain suffix like *.c with emacsclientw.exe
```

The last two items are useful if you you want to open a file in emacs by double click on windows explorer. The ALTERNATE_EDITOR environment variable allows emacs to start a new instance if none are running. Otherwise it will open the file on the already runnin emacs instance.

See also: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-Startup.html

Works for me. I use native windows emacs, not the cygwin one.